# Multiple Authentication ASP.Net Core - Docusign Authorization Code example + Custom Azure API

Tags: c#, azure, docusignapi

I am  using the Docusign Authorization Code example (https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp) to create a C# application connected to Docusign (which is already configured with our Single Sign On).

I also have another Azure App Registration to invoke my Custom API from Azure and I need to successfully get a token to invoke it.

I have successfully used **MSAL javascript** to invoke the custom API.

However, I am not sure if this is the safest or should i go with MSAL.NET (to do everything server side).
Anyone got ideas how to incorporate this additional MSAL.Net auth to my existing Docusign based C# code.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I think both MSAL js, and MASL.NET are secure, but there are some limitations to what you can do with the former. If all you need is a token to invoke an API - you should be good, but Microsoft support more things that you may need the server side code for.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) has a table that tells you all the different authentication flows Microsoft supports, and the different features each of them supports.

Comment: Thanks Inbar ! Regarding MSAL.js my only concern was having the clientid and scopes part of the HTML code (maybe its okay). With the DocuSign sample, I was not sure how to incorporate another auth scheme (based on Microsoft samples) on top of the DocuSign sample. Whenever my C# app needs to authenticate it goes to DocuSign so wanted to have 2 separate auth mechanisms..

Comment: Yes, this sample was designed as a simple one, so I understand your issue.
Two options:
1. You could just use JWT auth for DocuSign and replace the code in startup.cs to use another authentication (options object).
2. You could have 2 projects in your solution, each has this separately. The issue here is that each would have to be hosted on IIS separately, either separate folder or separate port when you navigate between them.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Inbar. Regarding the first option, I need the individual users to initiate the envelope, so would a JWT option work? The second option sounds bit complicated just for invoking my API. FYI I am using SSO to sign in the user

Comment: Not sure what "initiate" means. But you can still have different users use your app and all going through the same DocuSign user to send envelopes, that works ok.